# Received a python error when I clicked on new catalog in QGIS Geoserver

Tags: qgis, python, geoserver

What shall I do if I Python error message is there when I clicked on new catalog in QGIS Geoserver.

I have the same message: Python error: An error has occurred while executing Python code: See message log (Python Error) for more details.

Comment: Can you provide more details on the error message? screen shot?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @ZubairulIslam! Could you please [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/183088/edit) your question to include more details such as what the Python error message reads, QGIS version, screenshots etc?